# Corona newScrollView hideScrollBar still displays scroll bar

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

I declare Scroll View like this:

```
sv = widget.newScrollView{
    top = properties.y,
    left = properties.x,
    width = properties.moreGamesPanelWidth,
    height = properties.height,
    scrollWidth = properties.moreGamesPanelWidth,
    scrollHeight = lg.contentHeight,
    hideBackground = true,
    isBounceEnabled = false,
    horizontalScrollDisabled = true,
    isLocked = lock,
    listener = widgetTouchListener,
    hideScrollBar = true,
}
```

Unfortunately scroll bar is still visible, no matter what I set in "hideScrollBar".
Is there any possibility to hide the scroll bar?

Comment: This should work - are you pasting it exactly as you have it implemented? I can see there is a comma (,) at the end that isn't really supposed to be there? Have you edited something before posting it?

Comment: It is as it goes. I always put comma at the end, so I may add element without editing previous line then.

Answer (score 1):

I found an issue!
It happens when you declare two or more scrollViews. The last of them overrides the "hideScrollBar" setting. So there is no option to have two scrollViews, one with and one without scrollBar.

Here is the code which proves the issue

properties.lua

```
local properties = {}

--device dimensions
properties.width = display.contentWidth + display.screenOriginX * -2
properties.height = display.contentHeight + display.screenOriginY * -2
properties.x = display.screenOriginX
properties.y = display.screenOriginY
properties.center = { x = properties.x + properties.width / 2, y = properties.y + properties.height / 2 }

return properties
```

main.lua

```
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )


local properties = require("properties")
local widget = require("widget")

local sceneGroup = display.newGroup()

local lg = display.newGroup()
local lg2 = display.newGroup()

local bg = display.newRect(properties.center.x, properties.center.y, properties.width, properties.height)
bg:setFillColor(0.2, 0.2, 0.1)
sceneGroup:insert(bg)
local menuRect1 = display.newRect(100, 50, 200, 100)
menuRect1:setFillColor(0.8, 0.1, 0.1)
lg:insert(menuRect1)
local menuRect2 = display.newRect(100, 160, 200, 100)
menuRect2:setFillColor(0.1, 0.1, 0.9)
lg:insert(menuRect2)


local menuRect11 = display.newRect(100, 50, 200, 100)
menuRect11:setFillColor(0.8, 0.1, 0.1)
lg2:insert(menuRect11)
local menuRect22 = display.newRect(100, 160, 200, 100)
menuRect22:setFillColor(0.1, 0.1, 0.9)
lg2:insert(menuRect22)

local sv
local sv2

sv = widget.newScrollView{
    top = properties.center.y - lg.contentHeight * 0.5 - 100,
    left = properties.center.x - lg.contentWidth * 0.5,
    width = lg.contentWidth +20,
    height = lg.contentHeight -80 ,
    scrollHeight = lg.contentHeight,
    hideBackground = true,
    isBounceEnabled = false,
    hideScrollBar = true,
    horizontalScrollDisabled = true,
    isLocked = false,
}

sv2 = widget.newScrollView{
    top = properties.center.y - lg.contentHeight * 0.5 + 100,
    left = properties.center.x - lg.contentWidth * 0.5 ,
    width = lg.contentWidth +20,
    height = lg.contentHeight -80 ,
    scrollHeight = lg.contentHeight,
    hideBackground = true,
    isBounceEnabled = false,
    hideScrollBar = false,
    horizontalScrollDisabled = true,
    isLocked = false,
}

sv:insert(lg)
sv2:insert(lg2)

sceneGroup:insert(sv)
sceneGroup:insert(sv2)
```

Comment: I really doubt this. How about you show the code that creates the two scrollviews and adds them to the storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that corona's documentation is wrong, the property to set scroll bar visibility is not `hideScrollBar = false` it is `autoHideScrollBar = false`.

Had me stuck for days!